# How to display the owl Carousel navigation in the center?

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I am using the owl.carousel.js plugin for the content slide. The slider is working but I need navigation buttons in the center.

**I tried**

I set the `position: relative` to the class `.owl-nav` and `position: absolute;top;top: 50%;` to the class `.owl-nav div`.

Also, I set `.owl-prev{left: 0;} .owl-next{right: 0;}`

I am using `display: flex;` because I want to display the navigation arrows in the center of the circle.

But still not able to display the navigation in the center. Can you help me where I am wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
       navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
       slideSpeed : 300,
       margin:10,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      autoplay:false,
      items : 1, 
      itemsDesktop : false,
      itemsDesktopSmall : false,
      itemsTablet: false,
      itemsMobile : false,
      loop:true,
      nav:true,
      navText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left' aria-hidden='true'></i>","<i class='fa fa-angle-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>"]
  });
});
```

```css
.left_50{
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#owl-example{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
body .owl-nav{
  position: relative;
}

body .owl-nav div{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
border:1px solid #000;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 50%;
}
body .owl-prev{
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
}
body .owl-next{
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
}
body .owl-prev i, body .owl-next i{
  margin: auto;
}


#owl-example .owl-item{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
#owl-example .owl-item p{
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<div class="left_50">
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="owl_text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p> </div>
  <div class="owl_text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p> </div>
  <div class="owl_text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p> </div>
  <div class="owl_text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am getting the output like this

[image]

I need output like this

[image]

Comment: this will help --> https://www.freakyjolly.com/owl-carousel-2-customize-navigation-next-prev-arrows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing some style and viola:

```
body .owl-nav{
  position: initial;
}

body .owl-nav div{
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
border:1px solid #000;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 50%;
}

body .owl-prev{
  left: -20px;
  display: flex;
  background-color:white;
}

body .owl-next{
  right: -20px;
  display: flex;
  background-color:white;
}
```

**Codepen link:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eyzaPP

Comment: Glad to help! :D

Answer (score 3):

try out this CSS

```
.owl-carousel {
    position: relative;
}
.owl-next, .owl-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.owl-next {
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
}
.owl-prev{
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
}
```

here is the site i applied it FYR:http://bhadbhabie.com/

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
body .owl-nav{
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I removed. It is displaying inside the box now but it's not in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Edited the positioning of `.owl-nav` and then gave the circle buttons a white background each.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed: 300,
    margin: 10,
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    autoplay: false,
    items: 1,
    itemsDesktop: false,
    itemsDesktopSmall: false,
    itemsTablet: false,
    itemsMobile: false,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    navText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left' aria-hidden='true'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-angle-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>"]
  });
});
```

```css
.left_50 {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#owl-example {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

body .owl-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 21px);
  width: 107%;
  left: -21px;
}

body .owl-nav div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

body .owl-prev {
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
}

body .owl-next {
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
}

body .owl-prev i,
body .owl-next i {
  margin: auto;
}

#owl-example .owl-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#owl-example .owl-item p {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<div class="left_50">
  <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="owl_text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
    </div>
    <div class="owl_text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
    </div>
    <div class="owl_text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
    </div>
    <div class="owl_text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why you used? top: calc(50% - 21px);width: 107%;left: -21px; Can you explain it?

Comment: If you position just 50% from the top, your buttons won't be aligned perfect vertically to the middle because the buttons are being positioned from their top edge, and not through the middle. Since the buttons are 42px in height you can subtract 21px to find their center line. The larger width allows the buttons to overlap the slide and `left: -21px;` pulls the whole container back horizontally centered.